# Is crestfallen the correct word for sympathetic sadness?

Tags: word-choice

My cat died recently and a friend said he was "Crestfallen for your loss." I believe he was trying to say he was deeply sympathetic and sad, but I understand crestfallen to mean disappointment and dejection – like hanging (fallen) your head (crest) in disappointment after something doesn't go as you hoped.

Is this an OK usage?

Comment: People just don't know their own language very well. This quesiton, however, is not suitable for ELU. It will be migrated to ELL probably. But it seems to me you have answered your own question.